# Setting html table tag height

Tags: html, css

### Description:

While working with a library's table, I encountered a problem with setting the height for HTML `table` tag. I won't mention a particular library because I found out it's replicable with just a bare HTML `table` tag, as well as with elements with property display set to `table` or `table-row-group`.
HTML `table` tag doesn't respond to setting property height. It might be set in pixels, it might be in a percentage (while the parent has defined height), or in other units.
A `table` with a height, overflow set to hidden and content overflowing the height visually doesn't hide overflow and, in dev tools, has the height of its children instead of the given one.

### Here is a minimal example:

```css
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}

.table {
  height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: blue;
}

.table tbody {
  background-color: rgb(50, 205, 0);
  height: 40px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="App">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>test</tr>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>test1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>test2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>test3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>test4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>test5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>test6</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

### Live example

[image: Edit bold-paper-etuw5f]

### What I want to achieve:

1. I want to give a table a particular height to hide content that overflow that height.
2. I want to build a table that fits a parent or given height, that has a static size header and body that is similar to `overflow-y: auto`

I'm also curious why `display: table` doesn't behave predictably and doesn't work with `overflow`. If possible, I would ask for an explanation.

Comment: _"My primary goal was to make a table responsive wrapped with flexbox and flex-shrink & flex-grow."_ - `flex` does not work like that.

Comment: It doesn't answer my question. I didn't ask about flex. Anyway, flex does work like that: https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-chaplygin-16q8c2

Comment: There is nothing _responsive_ about that example you linked to, and that specific use of `display: flex;` in `.App` does not achieve anything of value: there is no point using `display: flex` for a single flex-item.

Comment: You still don't respond to the question. I didn't ask about responsiveness or how flexbox works. I present a minimal example as I think it doesn't worth writing more code not related to the question. I used it as an open phrase to my problem, as I found out it's not possible to play around responsive height if there is no control over height at all. With explicit height given in pixels table still has a different height. I added the "What I want to achieve" section at the bottom of my question. If it's not clear, please make it explicit.

Comment: You haven't yet explained what you mean by "manage a table's height" - and what do you expect should happen if a 1,000 row table (with all cells containing Lorem Ipsum filler text in `font-size: 72pt`) has `height: 100px;` set?

Comment: Good point.  1. table to have the height I gave it, 2. overflow to work like for other elements i.e. if content overflow height, it should behave as described by overflow property.

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question.

Comment: I updated the title and content. I hope it's cleaner now.